# Analytical solution of nonlinear Advection Diffusion equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Is there any analytical solution to the nonlinear Advection Diffusion equation of the following type?
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(f^{\alpha}f+f^{\beta}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)-f.$$
Where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are integers and $f$ is a distribution function.

Comment: From the equation you get $\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f\,dx = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty f\,dx$ , which is not compatible with $f$ being a probability distribution. Is the equation OK, and if yes, in what sense is it Fokker Planck (i.e. where does it come from)?

Comment: Such kind of equation arises in plasma physics also in various models of complex systems. These equations are of advection-diffusion type and sometimes also referred as Fokker-Planck equation. However their origin is not limited to probability distribution. I understand the concern of calling it Fokker Planck, so changed the name.